# Contributing to Spring Framework Reference Documentation?

Tags: spring

I am wondering if there is a way for public to contribute to Spring Reference documentation (e.g. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/).

I find typos occasionally.

I can't find any source code repository, or contact information.

I see `CONTRIBUTING-DOCUMENTATION.adoc` in the main repo, but I don't think it is the same thing? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING-DOCUMENTATION.adoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING-DOCUMENTATION.adoc) is the how-to contribute to the reference guide. Tothether with the [Contributing Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) that explains what you need to do and take care of when contributing.

The actual source file used for the reference guide can be found in the same repository.

The flow is basically, create a JIRA issue, fix it, create a pull request, refer to pull request from JIRA.

Comment: Thanks. It seems GitHub's search fails to index such a large file. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Getting+Started%22&type=Code Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

One way i've seen for community to help contribute is by lodging tickets on [jira.spring.io](http://jira.spring.io).
If you provide the issue and provide answer to it they will review and give you relevant feedback on it.